# image similarity using image caption

Tags: image, computer-vision, deep-learning

I've seen a lot of methods that compares two images and compute similarities using CNN. But it seems these methods don't reflect the contexts in images. So do you think it will be better method/metric of image similarity, if there is a well generated images description(caption) and use it as a new metric of image similarity?

And what are the limitations of computing image similarity using CNN?
thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: and how are those CNNs trained, you are talking about? and why do these methods not reflect contexts in images?